# The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b). Click OK to close the application

Tags: windows-7

So since I have completely reinstalled my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit I have been getting a lot of errors, I have been looking for solutions for about 3 months now. One of the errors I am facing is this., a solution will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Following is the error I received - [image: The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b). Click OK to close the application.]

Comment: Have you tried running 'sfc /scannow' in elevated command prompt

Comment: Yes, I have it doesnt seem to fix ANY problems including some otehr problems I am facing.

Comment: Report the issue and see what they say>>>https://signup.buildbox.com/reportAnIssue

Answer (score 0):

Your system is missing some dependencies. I advise you to make some updates with `Windows Update` download updates from **Net Framework 4.5 or higher**, install **Java Runtime**, **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (*or higher*) Redistributable**, check the version of your **DirectX**, being it an obsolete version, update it!

Download the `AIO package` (it already contains some tools that I mentioned above and others, but download them separately being the most recent, I believe this link is not up to date these days)

- .NET Framework
- Allgemeine Runtime Detection
- Microsoft DirectX 9.0: Redistributable
- Java Runtime Environment
- Visual C++ Runtimes
- Adobe Flash Player
- Adobe Shockwave Player
- Microsoft Silverlight
- Microsoft DirectX for Managed Codes
- Microsoft Visual J Sharp

[Link Download the Package](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0h-NHKRYdb3cHRDQzlXMzNpNGc/view)

I hope it helped you, this method already served me a while ago, because I am already a long time Windows user. Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded the whole package and installed but it still doesnt seem to fix the error